# How to find mapping between WCF service element and WPF UI element

Tags: wcf, automation, soapui, parasoft

I have a WPF application that is calling a WCF SOAP service. Development framework  of the application is MVVM. In the WCF service we make a call to a database and return some items. The webservice response is a huge xml response and I am a QA engineer trying to write webservice automated tests.I basically have to write assertions on the XML response elements, which is easy to do with the automated tool I am using.

My problem however is I do not exactly know which WPF element on UI is mapped to which element in WCF service response. Most of the UI element names differ from XML element name in service response.  When the WCF services were first implemented I was not on the project from the bgeinning and I am also told that there was never a technical specification document and xsd's etc on this. The service response is a huge a xml list of elements and not all xml elements are  binded to UI. So I have to know this mapping information to be able to do assertions correctly. Please suggest on how to find this mapping between UI to webservice?

Comment: Talk to the UI developers? Look through the UI source code?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the Service Trace Viewer tool. This way you can interact with the UI and see which service is being called.
See the Using the Service Trace Viewer Tool section here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023(v=vs.110).aspx

As for tracing information, if your AUT doesn't produce any logs, then I advise suggest referring the Configuring Tracing section of the link above to your developers. This information may be useful to you later in life if you're tasked with gathering metrics on the web service transfers.

Comment: This is great, thanks for the suggestion. I downloaded the Microsoft Windows SDK. I however do not have access to update the system.diagonostics on config file. I will discuss about this tool with the developer and try this out.